# How to make a dynamic circle on the map?

Tags: bing-maps, windows-phone-7.1, bing, windows-phone-7

I have a point on the map (a custom pushpin, which does not grow according to the zoom), and I want to have a circumference based on the accuracy of GPS, that will change size according to the zoom. Any idea how to create this circle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post is more focused on drawing shapes on bing maps control.

http://awkwardcoder.blogspot.com/2011/10/drawing-shapes-on-top-of-bing-maps-in.html

Answer (score 2):

These [two](http://awkwardcoder.blogspot.com/2011/10/tessellating-shapes-on-top-of-bing-maps.html) [articles](http://awkwardcoder.blogspot.com/2011/11/tessellating-shapes-on-top-of-bing-maps.html) show how to create shapes on top of a map.
They do a bit more than you need but I'm sure there's more than enough for your needs there.